# Prevent user side to print RDP Session

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop, snipping-tool

I'm doing a project with some virtual machines, where I'm going to run a program where users can't save print on their machines. I already removed the Snipping tool from the server and the print screen is blocked. However, if the user uses the snipping tool on his machine, he can still take a screenshot. Is there any program or something that can block or leave a black screen when the user tries to print the screen in the RDP session? Does anyone know of any software that might help?

I have McAfee DLP, but RDP configuration is limited and doesn't work for this case. Thanks in advance!

Also, i have a rule in mobiles, that even someone take a screen shot with their mobiles, they cannot share that info, whatsapp, messages, etc.

The problem i want sove is to avoid leak this info on PC on emails, etc.

Comment: What't the purpose of this requirement? Even if this would be possible, what I think it isn't, the user could always take a photo of the screen with a camera or smartphone. Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: We have a rule in mobile that if even they take picture with their phone, they cannot share the information on whatsapp or messages. This requirement is only to prevent the users to take the screen shot and share on email, etc.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add requested information. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: If you don't control the user side then saving images of what is displayed in an RDP session will always be possible.